# How to draw a perpendicular line from any point in space to the detected plane

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I do have something like the following figure.

[image]

I insert my model on a detected horizontal plane (table). So the red dot is the origin. The green dot however I know from a database which describes the build. You can think of an arm where each segment can get bend on its join by the user. Thats why the green dot will move. Is there an easy way to draw a perpendicular line from the green dot to the ground plane or do i need to do the math?

Bonus: i need to know the distance (blue line) from the origin to the point where this line hits the ground. I could think of somthing like a hit-test.

many thanks in advance

UPDATE:
If I'm not mistaken, realitykit offers physics. The easiest way would be to attach a rope to the green dot which then "hangs" down to the ground. figuratively speaking. I don't know if this is possible and if so, how to do it.

Comment: Mathematically this is simple. As long as you know the length of the lines and the angles and directions they are bending in. What information do you have in the code when the user is making these changes?

Comment: That's the point, the information from the database is not always reliable. It can happen that the point where the sibling joins is not always 100% the length of the parent.

Comment: Ah, ok. But the green point is something that you are given and is accurate?

Comment: the more I thing ... I think the length of each individual model parts is irrelevant as long as I have every insertion point. or am i wrong? the green point is a absolute point on the last model segment itself.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, realitykit offers physics. The easiest way would be to attach a rope to the green dot which then "hangs" down to the ground. figuratively speaking. I don't know if this is possible and if so, how to do it.